# Собственная реализация календаря

Tags: java, календарь

Хочу сделать свою реализацию календаря для проведения различных расчетов.

Простой пример:
График работы пятидневка в которой время есть с 8 до 13 и с 14 до 17. Выходные сб, вс. Дальше использовать все функции библиотеки `java.time`, например легко посчитать количество рабочих часов и прочее.

Не пойму с какого конца потянуть, как понимаю нужно изменить `java.time.clock` и в `java.time.crono` для своего региона календарь, но меня путает наличие `TemporalField`. В общем не могу разобраться с новой библиотекой, наведите на мысль.

Задача в планировании работ по периоду. Была идея сделать свою собственную реализацию календаря в котором было столько часов/минут в каждом дне сколько в графике. В таком случаем можно было леко вычислять например Period и прочие плюшки java.time именно по нужному календарю.

Самый простой пример: 10 января рабочее время 8-12 14-18 11 января рабочее время 9-11 12-18 сколько рабочих часов с 11 часов 10 января до 16 часов 11 января. Уже реализовал банально расчетом и прочим, но так было бы красиво

Comment: А что именно не получается? Попробуйте привести пример конкретной задачи (например, количество рабочих часов с такого-то по такое-то).

Comment: Задача в планировании работ по периоду. Была идея сделать свою собственную реализацию календаря в котором было столько часов/минут в каждом дне сколько в графике. В таком случаем можно было леко вычислять например Period и прочие плюшки java.time именно по нужному календарю.
Самый простой пример 
10 января рабочее время 8-12 14-18
11 января рабочее время 9-11  12-18
сколько рабочих часов с 11 часов 10 января до 16 часов 11 января. 
Уже реализовал банально расчетом и прочим, но так было бы красиво.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, добавил их в вопрос (если что, это можно сделать кнопкой «править»). По мне так задача довольно непростая и правильно написанный расчет будет проще в понимании. Может кто-нибудь предложит элегантное решение.

Comment: Спасибо за корректировку, у меня такое ощущение что просто нужна своя реализация нужного класса с переопределением функции получения времени по конкретному дню, но покапался пока не нашел.